# Java - Cannot gather 2D array inside vector

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, vector, undo-redo, image-editor

As I mentioned in my previous (not ansvered) question, I'm making a image editor that can be embeded to my program. So I came to a point, where I decided that image editor must have undo and redo. So I wrote this code:

```
public Vector<Color[][]> undo = new Vector<Color[][]>();
size = 16;
public Color[][] chroma = new Color[size][size];
//These are variables

public void saveRevision(){
    System.out.println("Saving: " + current);
    undo.insertElementAt(chroma.clone(), current);
    current++;
    /*for (int i = 0; i < (undo.size()-1); i++) {
        if(i > current){
        undo.remove(i);
        }
    }*/
}

public void undo(){
    if(current > 0){
        System.out.println("Gathering: " + (current-1));
        current--;
        /*Color[][] c = undo.get(current);
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(c[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }*/
        /*for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                chroma[i][j] = null;
            }
        }*/
        chroma = undo.get(current);
        repaint();
    }
}

public void redo(){
    if((undo.size()-1) > current){
        System.out.println("Gathering: " + (current+1));
        current++;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                chroma[i][j] = null;
            }
        }
        chroma = undo.get(current);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I somehow cant write inside an array from that vector that has all the chroma revisions.
As you can see, I tried everything, but "chroma" variable does not seem to be changed. Em I doing something wrong?

Just forgot to mention: Undo and Redo are triggered using JButton, Revision is made everytime the mouse button is released.

Comment: `Color[][]` - that must be incredibly slow and need horrible amounts of memory. Also, read up on deep copies.

Comment: Nevermind, its fast enaugh for my needs :) Thank you anyway :) (What would you use instead of 2d arrays?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be, that for undo-redo to work the undo queue has to contain immutable data.

This means that every change (atomic group of changes) to `chroma`  would need a new 2D array copy; expensive.

The solution is to keep only the *change actions*  in the undo/redo queue.

In Java there is the AbstractAction which implements the Action interface, and as example for edits: [UndoManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html). Maybe do a bit of research on that.

(Also abstain from Vector, an ArrayList will not give comments.)

---

A bit better explained:

`chroma[][]` is the current state. For an undo/redo facility one need to change this state to an earlier one. Now one could store for every point in time with an undo to a prior moment the *entire state*, a copy of `chroma`.
A better way could be to store the *change* between two states. So if `chroma[47][11]` was changed from `A` to `B` store just the action pair:

```
undo: chroma[47][11] = A;
redo: chroma[47][11] = B;
```

This (more effort needing) alternative is often more practical.

It might be that the original choice is more direct: saving copies of `chroma`. Then assigning to chroma by some user action, should never change a saved state: the copies must be immutable = unchangeable, its internal state not depending on something changeable.

So, the copy ie need because of:

```
Color[][] chroma = ...;
Color[][] falseCopied = chroma;
chroma[3][4] = c;
// Now also `falseCopied[3][4].equals(c)`.
```

A real copy can be done:

```
public static Color copy(Color[][] grid) {
    Color[][] copied = new Color[grid.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; ++i) {
        copied[i] = Arrays,copyOf(grid[i], grid[i].length);
    }
    return copied;
}
```

Here one does not need to make a copy of every Color itself, because Color is "immutable", i.e. you cannot change its internal state. Something like `color.setBlue(23)` does not exist.

Comment: Can you explane this a little bit? :) Im quite new in programming :)

Comment: Sorry, explained a bit clearer now in the answer. What my answer simply boils down to: you might have shared the same `Color[][]` object, modifying all simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the [Java Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and re-architect your code. For example the Java Vector class is considered obsolete and deprecated (also a Vector is thread safe and since you probably call this thing on the EDT, judging from the JButton use, there is no need for that). Also using a low level multi dimensional array can be useful if you have some really specific (performance) requirements but I don't think thats the case in your scenario.

There are far easier and more readable ways to accomplish what you want with high level Java collection constructs.

Comment: Tried it, but it still doesn't work. Thank you for the answer anyway. :) Will post updates if i succeed. :P